# Vue.js - How do I relocate computed properties into an external library file?

Tags: vue.js

I'm new to Vue and was just assigned to an existing Vue project. I noticed the computed properties of one component were getting to around 200 lines. Can computed properties be relocated into an external .ts file and imported? If so, what would the import look like?

Everything I've seen has the computed properties located in the component itself. I'm not even sure it's 'allowed', and if it is I wouldn't know how to import it and then utilize it in the component.

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I don't know if it helps but you can create a mixin. [Read here about them](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html)

So you have `computed.js`:

```
export const computed = {
 computed: {
   my_comp_prop() {
     //some code
   }
 }
}
```

And then in your components:

```
import { computed } from './computed'

export default {
 mixins: [computed],
 //more code
}
```

In the end everything will merge in your component instance. Please don't forget to read about mixins and also about [Custom Option Merge Strategies](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Custom-Option-Merge-Strategies)

Comment: thanks! That sounds reasonable for the entire computed properties section. Is there an equivalent for a computed property itself? So say I have 10 computed properties, but one of them is really long and just crowds things up. Is it possible to reference a mixin or external library from the computed property itself?